# Memory management with UIPageControl and child ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

In my project I used this tutorial to `addChildViewControllers`: http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168 In the tutorial there are only 3 view controllers on the storyboard. In my project (ARC) I got alot more view controllers and I also add some of the view controllers that are on the storyboard more than once.So for example:

```
  [self addChildViewController:firstViewController];
  [self addChildViewController:firstViewController];
  [self addChildViewController:firstViewController];
  [self addChildViewController:secondViewController];
  [self addChildViewController:secondViewController];
  [self addChildViewController:thirdViewController];
```

and the problem is that this takes much memory because they are all loaded. My question is how can I reduce this?

Comment: Why do you add the same view controller multiple times? AFAIK `addChildViewController` just creates a relationship between the parent and the child view controller instance, so calling it multiple times shouldn't be necessary. The parent-child relationship is created to forward rotation events, for example. Are all view controllers visible at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the tutorial, I have a better suggestion for you: Use [`UIPageViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html). It does exactly what you need and it uses a dataSource protocol so you don't have to keep all the view controllers in memory. I'm pretty sure that this is what you want. Don't roll your own page view controller unless you have a very good reason for doing so.

[WWDC 2011 Session 102](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) will give you a good introduction to `UIPageViewController` and container view controllers in general.

Comment: The problem is I've already made my app, so is there an easy way to change it from my app to the UIPageViewController you gave me? Is this also based on the storyboard view controllers like in the tutorial? And does it include the scroll/swipe like in the tutorial?

Comment: It works with storyboards and it definitely supports swiping. I don't know the details of your app, but you should definitely watch the WWDC session video, I'm sure it will help you whether you use UIPageViewController or roll your own container view.

Comment: Thanks for your help, what my app actually is is like this: Its some sort of story, where the users swipe through (like a book) the difference with a book is that there are images, labels on the view controllers and also text fields where they need to fill something in. Is it easy to switch to the UIPageViewController because I've done everything like the tutorial...